# Uncaught RuntimeException: Unexpected data in output buffer

Tags: php, slim

I created a Mysql database in XAMPP server and I now I wanted to insert data by postman to database.
I did all that true but unexpected error occurred.
It seems error is because of app.php of Slim.

Here is my index.php.

```
<?php

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../includes/dboperation.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->post('/createuser', function (Request $req, Response $res) {
    if (IsEmpty(array('name', 'password'), $res)) {
        $reqdata = $req->getParsedBody();

        $name = $reqdata['name'];
        $pass = $reqdata['password'];

        $hashed_password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $db = new DbOperation();

        $result = $db->createUser($name, $hashed_password);
        if ($result == USER_CREATED) {
            $Message = array();
            $Message['error'] = false;
            $Message['msg'] = 'User had been created successfully !';
            $response->write(json_encode($Message));
            return $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')->withStatus(201);

        } else if ($result == USER_FAIELD) {
            $Message = array();
            $Message['error'] = true;
            $Message['msg'] = 'Problem occurred !';
            $response->write(json_encode($Message));
            return $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')->withStatus(422);
        } else {
            $Message = array();
            $Message['error'] = true;
            $Message['msg'] = 'Username is invalide !';
            $response->write(json_encode($Message));
            return $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')->withStatus();
        }
    }
});


function IsEmpty($required_param, $response)
{
    $er = false;
    $er_code = '';
    $request_param = $_REQUEST;
    foreach ($required_param as $param) {
        if (!isset($request_param[$param]) || strlen($request_param[$param]) <= 0) {
            $er = true;
            $er_code .= $param . ', ';
            $response->write(json_encode($er_code));
        }
    }
    if ($er) {
        $err = array();
        $err['error'] = true;
        $err['msg'] = 'Losted param : ' . $er_code;
        $response->write(json_encode($err));
    }
    return $er;
}

$app->run();

?>
```

Here is dboperation.php

```
<?php

class DbOperations
{
    private $con;

    function __construct()
    {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/dbconnect.php';
        $db = new DbConnect;
        $this->con = $db->connect();
    }

    public function createUser($Name, $Password)
    {
        if (!$this->NameValidation($Name)) {

            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name,password) VALUES(?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $Name, $Password);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                return USER_CREATED;
            } else {
                return USER_FAILED;
            }
        } else {
            return USER_EXISTED;
        }
    }

    private function NameValidation($Name)
    {
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $Name);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0;
    }
}

?>
```

This is the error:

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant DB_HOST - assumed 'DB_HOST' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in E:\xamp\htdocs\test\includes\constant.php on line 2

Warning: Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in E:\xamp\htdocs\test\includes\constant.php on line 3

Warning: Use of undefined constant DB_PASS - assumed 'DB_PASS' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in E:\xamp\htdocs\test\includes\constant.php on line 4

Warning: Use of undefined constant DB_NAME - assumed 'DB_NAME' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in E:\xamp\htdocs\test\includes\constant.php on line 5

Warning: Use of undefined constant USER_CREATED - assumed 'USER_CREATED' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in E:\xamp\htdocs\test\includes\constant.php on line 7

Warning: Use of undefined constant USER_EXISTED - assumed 'USER_EXISTED' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in E:\xamp\htdocs\test\includes\constant.php on line 8

Warning: Use of undefined constant USER_FAILED - assumed 'USER_FAILED' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in E:\xamp\htdocs\test\includes\constant.php on line 9

Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unexpected data in output buffer. Maybe you have characters before an opening <?php tag? in E:\xamp\htdocs\test\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php:625 Stack trace: #0 E:\xamp\htdocs\test\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(333): Slim\App->finalize(Object(Slim\Http\Response)) #1 E:\xamp\htdocs\test\public\index.php(69): Slim\App->run() #2 {main} thrown in E:\xamp\htdocs\test\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php on line 625
```

Actually when I pass the require parameters to insert I get nothing to show that means empty page has shown and when I don't pass them the error occur but I expected the response that i coded.

Thank you for read this carefully!

Comment: Where are your constants defined?

Comment: You use non-existent constants in E:\xamp\htdocs\test\includes\constant.php. Need to declare constants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

Firstly, you haven't defined the Constants, which means warnings are generated in your log. Check your `constants.php` and make sure the constants are actually defined.

Secondly, you probably have `display_errors` on. Never do that. Set it off either in your ini file, or with `ini_set('display_errors', false);`.

The fatal error is caused by Output already having started before you expected it to. By turning `display_errors` off, your app should run (albeit you might still need to fix those constants!)

For the best error logging experience, set `error_reporting` to `-1`, turn `display_errors` off, and set a custom `error_log`. Then in the terminal, type `tail -f /path/to/error_log`. Your notices, warnings and errors will now scroll past in real time, without distorting your web page's display.